# I want to plot the error and the tree size of a gradient Boost

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn

I created a `GradientBoostingRegressor` with 700 trees and now I want to check, if the Tree is overfitted. Therefore I want to plot the error (y-axis) and the treesize (100, ... ,700  x-axis). But I could not find the answer how I get the prediction of each Tree. Now I have just the error for each datapoint. I searched for days now and I hope somebody could help me to find the answer. Thanks

```
gb_v2 = GradientBoostingRegressor(
    n_estimators = 700,
    learning_rate = 0.05,
    max_features = None,
    max_depth = 5,
    min_samples_leaf = 1,
    min_samples_split = 2,
    random_state = 42,
    min_impurity_decrease = 0
)
gb_v2.fit(X_train_v1, y_train_v1);
```

Comment: Hi! This looks like a machine learning question, and you might have better luck asking it here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the prediction of each tree using `staged_predict`. Here is a simple example on how to plot the error vs. number of trees based on sklearn's official [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_regularization.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-gradient-boosting-regularization-py).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

params = {'n_estimators': 700, 'random_state': 2}

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=0)

clf = GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# compute test set deviance
test_deviance = np.zeros((params['n_estimators'],), dtype=np.float64)

for i, y_pred in enumerate(clf.staged_predict(X_test)):
    test_deviance[i] = clf.loss_(y_test, y_pred)

step_size = 10

plt.plot((np.arange(test_deviance.shape[0]) + 1)[::step_size],
         test_deviance[::step_size],
         '-')

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel('Boosting Iterations')
plt.ylabel('Test Set Deviance')

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can vary the `step_size` to modify the detailing of the plot.

Comment: Thank you very much! My own plot looks almost like yours. I think that I dont need so much Boosting Iterations. Maybe just 500. Do you think thats the right conclusion about this plot? And could we recognize something about the fitting of the model?

Comment: I think 100 iterations itself would be enough for this model. search for knee curve, you get the idea about how to choose the value.